# Compiling a C++ program from cmd using TCC in turbo c++

Tags: c++, cmd, command-prompt, turbo-c++, dosbox

I am currently running Windows 10 64bit OS and I have install Turbo C4 suppose I don't to use the editor provided by Turbo C4 instead I want to write in a Notepad and then manually compile it using command prompt.

I am aware that Turbo C4 compiled programs won't run in our modern OS but we can use dosbox which is provided in Turbo C4.

Suppose my file name is `test.cpp`
Then what should I write in my console of command prompt in order to compile and run a c plus plus program using the TCC compiler provided by Turbo C4.

Guys please help me with this,

- (And by the way I am completely aware that the new modern compilers great to use instead of turbo but our school enforces us to use Turbo instead so I just want to write an editor program for my friends so All I need is a simple console command that can compile and run my CPP file.)

Comment: Have you tried to look in the directory where you installed it? In any sub-directories?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah I looked in but I could not compile a c plus plus file as it could not include any header file

Comment: @Marged  I'm not punishing them actually but I I kind of wanna create my own editor in which I am writing a batch script so that's why I need the command line code!

Comment: @Marged I want to create my own editor so I am writing a batch script to compile and run!

Comment: @Marged Its my own summer project

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Community edition is free. https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/ Cygwin is also free. http://www.cygwin.com/

Comment: Is this TinyCC or Turbo C? TCC is somewhat ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command line utility for compiling with Turbo C is called `tcc`.

You can compile your code like this: `tcc strange.cpp`. If the program was compiled correctly you will find a `strange.exe`. Put it on a computer that fulfills the requirements and run it or use your dosbox emulator.

You might need to set up environment variables to find header files and libraries.

To make your life easier I would create a (DOS) batch file with this content:

```
@echo off
SET PATH=%PATH%;Whatever_else_you_need
SET ...=...;Whatever_environment_variable_you_need
TCC %1.cpp
```

Then call this batch using `dosbox -c foo.bat strange`. See the [docs](https://www.dosbox.com/DOSBoxManual.html#Parameters)  of dosbox for more details.

If you want to run your exe immediately after compilation, just add ...

```
%1.exe
```

... to you batch file.

See here for some more details about Turbo C and compilation: https://codingfox.com/how-to-execute-a-c-program-in-command-prompt-using-turbo-c-compiler/

Comment: What if i have header files somewhere else other than turboC4 folder.

Comment: I am on windows 10 i think the tcc compiled programs wont run in usual cmd.

Can you please give me heads up in running that program through command prompt in the dosbox.

Comment: Suppose I have dosbox dot exe in C drive then what should I type in my command prompt so that my file 'test.cpp' gets compiled and next how to run it from the dosbox.

Comment: Thank you Marged, your your answer has helped me and is accurate as per the question still if you have get time have a look on my answer just below,  mine is a better solution do but is not accurate as per the question as I mentioned I need TCC compilers settings and you have done it.

Answer (score 1):

TCC now a days do not support C++ they only support C, so better download digital Mars C/C++ compiler.
 [your download available here](https://www.digitalmars.com/download/freecompiler.html)

Then go to bin directory in dm of downloaded folder then inside the wynn you can locate dmc.exe set it to your cmd environment variable,
and type `dmc file.cpp` in your shell and if there are no errors then you can find file.exe and run!

They can be run and compiled on usual x86 or x64 bit command prompt.

Same code you wrote in turbo c
Will work here too.

**Happy coding**

Comment: Thanks for confirming my doubts: I doubted that Turbo *C* is able to compile C*PP*

Answer (score 1):

I made a tool called `UCC` that lets you compile and run programs using **one simple command** with full support for the *Borland Graphics Interface*, you can use it in this case to build and run programs directly from the command line, without opening the TurboC/++ GUI. It works on both Windows and Unix like systems. Example usage:

`ucc --build test.cpp`

It is free and open source.

https://github.com/uditkarode/ucc/